# javascript Can I make an array of object?

Tags: arrays, object

I'am trying make an array of object.

```
var number = 0;
var name = 1;
var dKeyObj = new Object();
//var dKeyPiar = new Object();
var dKeyPiar = [];

function sendFakeData() {
    request(options, function (error, resp, body) {
        dKeyObj['name'] = name.toString(16).padStart(2, '0');  // hexa value
        dKeyObj['value'] = resp.headers['value'];
        dKeyPair[number++] = dKeyObj;
        console.log(dKeyPair[0]);
        if(number < 99)
            making();
        else
            //console.log('lasted data ' + dKeyPair[10]['name']);
            console.log('lasted data ' + dKeyPair[10]);
    });
}
```

I think the result is...
{ name: '01', value: '*the first value*'}
{ name: '01', value: '*the first value*'}
{ name: '01', value: '*the first value*'}
...
//latest data 0a
latest data { name: '0a', value: '*the tenth value*'}

But the log is...
{ name: '01', value: '*the first value*'}
{ name: '02', value: '*the second value*'}
{ name: '03', value: '*the third value*'}
...
//latest data 63
latest data [object, Object]


The index of dKeyPair is ignored.
Can I make an array of object?

Comment: You have a typo in "dkeyPiar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array = [];
var obj = {};
obj["name"] = "name";
obj["value"] = "val";
array.push(obj);
```

To push an object into an array we do the above.

Comment: I tried your code, but the result is same. I don't know what I'm missing...

Comment: Plus the code makes sense for the values you are getting.

Comment: I got it. I declared the global variable at outside of the function.

Comment: I think the push method copy the instance, not value. When I moved the variable inside I got the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can objects into array:

```
var dKeyObj1 = {'k1':'v1'};
var dKeyObj2 = {'k2':'v2'};

var arr = new Array();
arr.push(dKeyObj1);
arr.push(dKeyObj2);
```